# Can I mix a Browserify bundle/module scripts with <script src> included scripts?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browserify, es6-modules

I am working on a project that is adopting Browserify at a late stage.

We have many React components included manually, along with the their dependencies, as `<script>` tags where they are needed, including a handful of files including common React components.

```html
<!-- includes ComponentA and dependencies, including React -->
<script src="/js/browserify-bundle.js"></script>

<script src="/js/react.min.js"></script> <!-- React included here too -->
<script src="/js/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!-- ...more dependencies... -->
<script src="/js/common-components.js"></script> 
<!-- ...more components/script includes... -->
```

I'm working on the first React component being written as an ES6 module, but due to our situation the module dependencies end up being loaded twice; first from the manual dependency given in the script tag and then from the Browserify bundle.

Removing the script tag including React breaks the common components, but leaving it in causes React [duplication errors like this](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html) because there are two Reacts floating around there.

Does this mean that there's no way of temporarily bridging this gap by (for example) telling Browserify to use the manual React include? With this, we could start using Browserify piecemeal. Is it absolutely necessary to make all our components/scripts into ES6 modules and make everything use Browserify through and through to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use [`browserify-shim`](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim) for your situation. It allows you to
declare that a module is already available from the global scope.

In your `package.json`:

```
"browserify-shim": {
  "react": "global:React"
},
"browserify": {
  "transform": [ "browserify-shim" ]
}
```

Hopefully that will allow you to bridge the gap for now.

Comment: Yes, this worked. I spent hours looking for something, then posted the question, then basically found `browserify-shim` about five minutes after I posted the question (of course). I had trouble getting it working (it didn't seem to be able to resolve the path to `package.json`), but it does work now, and what I have in my `package.json` is basically exactly that, so I'm accepting this.